# drag and drop options

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a simple tool. If I drag n drop files ,folders into my form it will automatically open the corresponding file and folder. Now I want to do it for `.lnk` files(shortcuts) if I drag a `.lnk` file, it must open the target file.

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is a simple mock up but you should get the idea...

First add the **COM 'Windows Script Host Object Model'** reference to your project.

Next include the line...

```
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
```

For this example I just used a list box control but use what ever you want... If you handle the **DragEnter** event, you can get the file name passed as an argument. You can then create a **WshShell** object to get the links target path.

```
private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    String[] fileName = (String[])e.Data.GetData("FileName");

    WshShell shell = new WshShell();
    IWshShortcut link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(fileName[0]);

    String targetPath = link.TargetPath;

    listBox1.Items.Add(targetPath);
}
```

The code doesn't handle non shortcuts etc but it should give you a starter... :)