# swap picturebox in drag and drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Hi I've been trying to do a swap between two PictureBoxes with drag and drop, the code I'm using to do the drag and drop is [C# Drag and Drop from one Picture box into Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004682/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-from-one-picture-box-into-another)

But I have 9 pictureboxes and i need the swap to be dynamic, cant manage to get the name of the picturebox from where the image is coming so i can do the swap, would love some help on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

A global variable will do your thing like this;

```
PictureBox from;
```

when a drag starts from picturebox1 ;

```
From = picturebox1;
```

when a drag starts from picturebox2 ;

```
From = picturebox2;
```

when DragDrop a picturebox the `from` variable will be the images source