# How to Drag & Drop PictureBox From One Windows Form To Another

Tags: c#, image, forms, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I am building a simple drag and drop game using windows forms. Its like a jigsaw puzzle. I want to drag pictures from one form to another to complete the puzzle. Is there a way to do this with a PictureBox. It seems to be the only property without the AllowDrop function. Source code below.

[image]

I want to drag images from the form on the left to the form on the right.

I was following this tutorial but I cannot get my head around it.
[C# Drag and Drop from one Picture box into Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004682/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-from-one-picture-box-into-another)

**Form Right**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DragDropGame
{
    public partial class ChildFormTwo : Form
    {
        public ChildFormTwo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox3.DragEnter += pictureBox3_DragEnter;
            pictureBox3.DragDrop += pictureBox3_DragDrop;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form Left**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DragDropGame
{
    public partial class ChildFormTwo : Form
    {
        public ChildFormTwo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox3.DragEnter += pictureBox3_DragEnter;
            pictureBox3.DragDrop += pictureBox3_DragDrop;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is completely missing a DoDragDrop() method call.  Don't ignore its return value.

Comment: See also [How to drag and drop a button from one panel to another panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11414007/719186)